# Verification email not coming through

Tags: installation, account

I am struggling to get the verification email to come through to me.

I have setup Magento on a server, and it says it's sent an email but it hasn't. And yes I've checked my spam.

Comment: have you configured the SMTP? without SMTP it will not work accurately

Comment: @HarshJayswal Kind of. I have changed ``` inet_interfaces = loopback-only ```
Inside of /etc/postfix/main.cf
But I don't if that's enough.

Comment: Install the below extension and configure it your email will start https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/